# moving rows between two data grid views

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, datagridview

I have two data grid views with button fields. I have to grant and revoke functions to as particular role. if I click the grant button it should be removed from the current grid view and should be shown in the other grid view. that's the scenario with both grid views. I have used databinding() from database in every click. it works fine but the problem is that when I click the button it moves to the top of the grid due to the data binding. I want to maintain the current position of the grid view without moving to the top. Any ideas? TIA.[image]

here is the code behind

```
protected void grdAllFunctions_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        int roleid = Convert.ToInt32(ddlUser.SelectedValue);
        int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        GridViewRow row = grdAllFunctions.Rows[rowIndex];
        int funcid = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Text);
        UserClass obj = new UserClass();
        try
        {
            if (ddlUser.SelectedValue == "0")
            {
                errorHandle(false, "Please Select the Role Name");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds.Merge(obj.checkgrantedfunctions(roleid, funcid));
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    errorHandle(false, "This Function is Already Assigned");
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    obj.grant(roleid, funcid);
                    errorHandle(true, "Successfully Granted");
                    DataSet dg = new DataSet();
                    dg.Merge(obj.ungrantedfunctions(roleid));
                    if (dg.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        grdAllFunctions.DataSource = null;
                        grdAllFunctions.DataSource = dg.Tables[0];
                        grdAllFunctions.DataBind();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        grdAllFunctions.DataSource = dg.Tables[0];
                        grdAllFunctions.DataBind();
                    }
                    DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
                    ds1.Merge(obj.grantedfunctions(roleid));
                    if (ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        grdGrantedFunctions.Visible = true;
                        grdGrantedFunctions.DataSource = ds1.Tables[0];
                        grdGrantedFunctions.DataBind();
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('" + Server.HtmlEncode(ex.Message) + "')</script>");
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the issue the scroll bars? And the jump of the grid to scroll up? You could try wrapping both in a update panel if this is the case.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal scroll bars aren't the problem. whole data grid reloads after databinding.

Comment: right, I get the part about the re-bind. But, if you wind up staying on the same position, then you may well not care about the re-bind then do you? You (most likely) have a scrollable GV inside of a div. So, right after the div that scrolls, surround the GV with a update panel. Then on post-backs, and including a re-bind of the grid, your scroll position in the GV will REMAIN where you are. But, I not 100% clear what you mean by the grid moving back to the top? you don't even have to re-bind the GV - any page post back will cause a jump back to top of page, but not with my suggestion

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal yeah the problem was the scrollable GV in the div.  I've enabled the paging and it works fine. thanks mate...!

Comment: As noted if you wanted to keep the scrolling then a update panel would work and even with a rebinding the scrolling position would not change. So dumping the scrolling and going with a pager will work, and so would using a update panel with scrolling will also work.

Answer (score 1):

At the end (after databinding), add a statement to focus on the next or previous GridViewRow - `GridView.Rows[{Next or Previous}].Focus();`

Answer (score 0):

scrollable GV in a div is the problem. paging resolves the problem.
[Follow This Method](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9b86d4/how-to-implement-paging-in-gridview-control-in-Asp-Net/)